# Execute javascript function after Struts action do some calcul

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts

I want to explain cause the title could be not so clear.
We have a jsp form with a submit button which call an action. 
In this active we go to a service which executes some methods to do some calculus. One of this calculus (value above or under a threshold) must change/execute a javascript function. In other words, after the action calculus in need to be able to execute a javascript function in the same jsp page.

***What i've done without success :***

I create a hidden property in JSP and 2 conditionals for true or false states. False state is given by default (in the Form in Java) to the property and works fine.
But when i change the value of the property in the form nothing change in JSP and the property still have a false value.
We can't go to another page, we stay at the same jsp page.

JSP is not evaluating in real time the value of this property ?

Any other option to communicate between action and jsp ?

**JSP property**

```
<nested:hidden property="quitProgressBar"></nested:hidden>
            <nested:equal value="true" property="quitProgressBar">
                <script>
            alert('Prueba JVE');
      </script>
            </nested:equal>
            <nested:equal value="false" property="quitProgressBar">
                <script>
        alert('Recien cargado');
      </script>
            </nested:equal>
```

Comment: Why don't you try to call your Struts action via Ajax? That way, once your action has responded, you can simply call your js function because you "never left" the client-side.

Comment: Don't left the client-side, stay on the same page and rewrite your code because it's written with the assumption to do it on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by calling the Struts2 action via Ajax. For example:

**FORM**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="param1" name="param1" type="text" />
    <input id="param2" name="param2" type="text" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        var param1 = $(this).find('#param1');
        var param2 = $(this).find('#param2');

        $.ajax({
          url: '/route/to/action',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            'param1': param1, /* setParam1(String param1) required!*/
            'param2': param2, /* setParam2(String param2) required!*/
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
              // DO SOMETHING
          },
          success: function (response) {
              // DO SOMETHING
          },
          error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(jqXhr);
              console.log(textStatus);
              console.log(errorThrown);
              // DO SOMETHING
          }
        });
    });
});
```

In the Struts2 controller do all the computations you need and the action return type must be JSON (have a look here [Strtus2 json plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html). Ajax magics!

Comment: <button type="submit">Submit</submit> ??